# How to insert strings so that every row has the same pattern

Tags: r, string, dataframe, tidyverse, stringr

This is a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76227586/pivoting-single-rows-into-rows-with-their-combined-values). How can I add *n* empty strings between *_* so that every row has *exactly* 10 words separated by *_* each?

- The data is:

```
> head(dfLong, 10)
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  word                                                                           
  <chr>                                                                          
1 Jason_Oscar_Maleeka_Janet_Gabriel_Raheema_Bryce_Nasreen_Hishaam_Thadduse       
2 Marcos_Daijah_Chassity_Carlito_Chidiebere_Matthew_Maureene_Jillian_Markus_Aaron
3 Ramziyya_Marquez_Kiera_Farajallah_Larisa_Davier_Shujaa_Vincent_Orlando_Joseph  
4 Desean_Chelsea_Faadil_Christopher_Aarifa_Joel_Matthew_Jacob_Aeones_Matthew     
5 Jacob_Savannah_Nadia_Kaleem    ### THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO CHANGE                                                
>
```

- Desired output:

```
1 Jason_Oscar_Maleeka_Janet_Gabriel_Raheema_Bryce_Nasreen_Hishaam_Thadduse       
2 Marcos_Daijah_Chassity_Carlito_Chidiebere_Matthew_Maureene_Jillian_Markus_Aaron
3 Ramziyya_Marquez_Kiera_Farajallah_Larisa_Davier_Shujaa_Vincent_Orlando_Joseph  
4 Desean_Chelsea_Faadil_Christopher_Aarifa_Joel_Matthew_Jacob_Aeones_Matthew     
5 Jacob_Savannah_Nadia_Kaleem_''_''_''_''_''_''   ## LIKE THIS
```

**Questions**:

**1**: I need EVERY row to have *exatcly* 10 words each. In cases in which the amount of words is not exactly divisible by 10, I want to insert empty strings between _, like this: _ ' ' _. `tidyverse` and `stringr` solutions would be much appreciated! Thanks!

**2**: Later on, I also need another df in which ALL rows are combined into a new cell. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040042/merge-rows-concatenating-the-contents-in-one-of-the-columns-separated-by-comma-r) helped me. But, before merging the rows, I need to make sure that I have exactly 10 words per row (later on, I'll be displaying every 10 words of this data in a UI using Js `split('_').slice(v,v+10).join("<br>"))`, I'll split them by 10 and display one below the other). Thanks in advance.

- Data:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(word = c("Jason_Oscar_Maleeka_Janet_Gabriel_Raheema_Bryce_Nasreen_Hishaam_Thadduse", 
"Marcos_Daijah_Chassity_Carlito_Chidiebere_Matthew_Maureene_Jillian_Markus_Aaron", 
"Ramziyya_Marquez_Kiera_Farajallah_Larisa_Davier_Shujaa_Vincent_Orlando_Joseph", 
"Desean_Chelsea_Faadil_Christopher_Aarifa_Joel_Matthew_Jacob_Aeones_Matthew", 
"Jacob_Savannah_Nadia_Kaleem")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: dput data is not the same as data in question

Comment: Oh! I've just corrected it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(
    # count number of words:
    N = str_count(word, "_") +1,
    # add placeholders:
  word = ifelse(N < 10, 
                str_c(word, "_", str_dup("''_", 9 - N), "''"), 
                word)
  ) %>%
  select(-N) 
                                                                             word
1        Jason_Oscar_Maleeka_Janet_Gabriel_Raheema_Bryce_Nasreen_Hishaam_Thadduse
2                                   Jacob_Savannah_Nadia_Kaleem_''_''_''_''_''_''
3 Marcos_Daijah_Chassity_Carlito_Chidiebere_Matthew_Maureene_Jillian_Markus_Aaron
4                      Ramziyya_Marquez_Shujaa_Vincent_Orlando_Joseph_''_''_''_''
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  word = c("Jason_Oscar_Maleeka_Janet_Gabriel_Raheema_Bryce_Nasreen_Hishaam_Thadduse", 
           "Jacob_Savannah_Nadia_Kaleem",
           "Marcos_Daijah_Chassity_Carlito_Chidiebere_Matthew_Maureene_Jillian_Markus_Aaron",
           "Ramziyya_Marquez_Shujaa_Vincent_Orlando_Joseph")
)
```

Comment: Yes, it is! Thank you! Would you mind explaning the logic behind the if/else statment?

Comment: Sure: `ifelse`takes three argments: the condition to be met (here: `N < 10`, i.e., `N` is smaller than 10), what to do if the the condition returns TRUE (here: string together (i) the vector `word`, (ii) an underscore `_`, the string `''_`9 times - N), and a concluding `''`, and (iii) what to do if the condition returns FALSE (here: just just `word` as is). Does this clarify things or do you need more clarification?